# npm not installing latest version of ngx-bootstrap 6.2.0

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ngx-bootstrap

I have ngx-bootstrap 5.6.2 and I want/need to install 6 or above, but when I try

> npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

and

> npm install ngx-bootstrap 6.2.0

It doesn't install it, it just uninstalls 5.6.2 and then reinstalls it.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the latest version not in npm? It says it is...
[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap)

Running

1. Angular 10
2. Bootstrap 4+

Comment: try to delete your package-lock.json before running the install command

Comment: do I do that with a npm delete or is there a different method to delete the package-lock stuff?

Comment: you can simply delete the file, or run $ rm package-lock.json from the terminal (make sure your current working directory in the terminal is the same directory as the package-lock.json)

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to rm files like that as I'm not an expert with angular project files. Wouldn't it be easier to just uninstall the npm and then install from scratch?

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling npm won't help with this. Use your file browser, IDE, or any way that you can delete the package-lock.json file. right-click -> delete. Then when you npm install, it will recreate the package-lock.json file for you with the correct build number of ngx-boostrap and all other packages that you have installed. you will have the version you want. also, you can try looking at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: ok,it worked! thanks